# Search for specific word and extract it into new colomn in Power BI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, text-extraction

Atm my data is like a list of sentence like following:

FPTS is our (Case ID)

Column

- FPTS-0009: needed help for software update
- Helped and customer doing frontend FPTS-0012
- This time the customer FPTS-0020 needed refresh data

I want to find the word "FPTS" and extract it's ID and have it inside a new colomn. As you can see the word I need to extract doesn't have the same position all the time! sometimes it shifts What I try to do is extract FPTS-xxxx from above which would be:

- FPTS-0009
- FPTS-0012
- FPTS-0029

would help a lot to find a solution!

Comment: is it always going to be FPTS-####?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string is always going to be FPTS-####, you can do the following:

```
Found_Text = iferror(MID('table'[column], find("FPTS", '8HP_Tatoo_Today_Link'[TEXT_1]), 9), "")
```

This uses the `FIND` function, which will return the position in the sentence where "FPTS" is found. Then it uses this in the `MID` function, which returns the string of characters with a start position and a length. The `find` is used to define the starting index and then the length is 9.

It is wrapped in an `IFERROR`, because if the `FIND` returns nothing(string doesn't contain "FPTS") it will throw an error.